# Building terms relations within a network

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to represent relationships between numbers in column A and their corresponding values in B.

```
A            B
Home     [Kitchen, Home, Towel]
Donald   [US, 02 , Donald, Trump]
Trump    [Trump,Family, Cat, Dog]
Dog      [Dog,Cat,Paws]
```

Numbers in column A and numbers in B are nodes in a graph. I would like to connect elements in B to A or to each other. For example:

- Home in A is linked with itself; if I look within B column (the value appears only in the first row), Home in B is connected to Kitchen and Towel (ingoing link);
- Donald is linked with itself in as Donald is only in B; however, Donald in B is connected also with US, 02 and Trump (ingoing link);
- Trump has an outgoing link with Donald and ingoing links (Family, Cat and Dog);
- Dog has an outgoing link with Trump and ingoing links (Cat and Paws).

The rule should be the following then:

- if a word in A is in another row in B, then create an outgoing link;
- for each word in B create an ingoing link to the word in A, if the word in A is also included in B.

How should I adjust my code?

```
file = file.assign(B=file.B.map(list)).explode('B')


G = nx.DiGraph()
nx.add_path(G, file['A'])
nx.add_path(G, file['B'])

nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting your table to a pandas `dataframe` and then looping through its rows you can add the corresponding edges like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
from pyvis.network import Network


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Home', ['Kitchen', 'Home', 'Towel']],
        ['Donald', ['US', '02' , 'Donald', 'Trump']],
        ['Trump', ['Trump','Family', 'Cat', 'Dog']],
        ['Dog', ['Dog', 'Cat' , 'Paws']]
    ],
    columns=['A', 'B']
)

G = nx.DiGraph()

for i, j in enumerate(df['A']):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if i != index:
            if j in row['B']:
                G.add_edge(row['A'], j)
        else:
            for n in row['B']:
                if j != n:
                    G.add_edge(j, n)

    if G.in_degree(j) == 0:
        G.add_edge(j , j)

N = Network(directed=True)  # using pyvis to show self loops as well

for n, attrs in G.nodes.data():
    N.add_node(n)

for e in G.edges.data():
    N.add_edge(e[0], e[1])

N.write_html('graph.html')
```

Which gave me the following graph:

[image]

Hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Hi Azim, yes this is what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help. Stupid easy question: how can I visualise the graph?

Comment: Hi @Math, This is not a stupid question at all, a lot of people have this problem, especially with large graphs. I usually prefer to use [pyvis] [1] because it's interactive and visually more pleasant as well. It also has a [Networkx integration] (https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#networkx-integration) which makes things easier. In the above answer the visualization is written in `graph.html`.

[1] : https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Azim. Following the last link you shared, I tried with `G.show('graph.html')` but I got this error: `AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'show'`. I think I am still missing something to visually reproduce the graph you created. I hope you can help me

Comment: Sure. You get this error because the `networkx.DiGraph` class doesn't have a method called `show()`. After adding the  nodes and edges from your `DiGraph` to `pyvis.network.Network` object that you created, you need to use its `write_html()` method to save the graph in the location you want and then open it with a browser For example if `N` is your `Network` object, you can save your graph with `N.write_html('path/to/your_graph.html')` or `N.show('path/to/your_graph.html')`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Azim. I did not add any path so it was difficult for me to look at the graph. Last question: the graphs is moving on the html link. How can I get a 'stable' or slow-moving image?

Comment: You can make the graph static if you set the `physics` parameter `False` when adding the nodes or edges. e.g.  `G.add_edge(i , j, physics=False)`.

Comment: Thank you @ Azim

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220073/discussion-between-azim-mazinani-and-math).